# How to remove only a single point after using the Integrate tool

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class

I have a layer of 7000 point features that were obtained through asset extraction utilizing LiDAR. A small portion of these features are what we consider duplicates and need to be removed, however they do not have the exact same coordinates as they are with in a few feet of one another. I used the integrate tool to move each point to their relative middle, but now I need to remove only one of the two points and am having trouble doing so. I attempted to use the delete identical tool based on the feature's xy positions, but it did not remove either point as their coordinates were not exactly the same. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using the near tool to calculate the distance to the nearest feature within itself. I set the radius of the near tool to what I deemed to be close enough together to be considered a duplicate and was then able to use the delete identical based on that field as the near dist was exactly the same for anyone that runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you dont care about attribution for duplicates. One idea is to create a list of unique coordinates and any point which falls within your distance tolerance (or maybe you round your coordinates idk what you're willing to accept) you retain the OID of the "duplicate" and create a layer based on those OIDs and run delete features? I hope this helps man.